# Как добавить нумерацию столбцов в GridView Yii2

Tags: yii2, gridview

Вобщем-то вопрос задан выше. Может чего пропустил в документации

Answer (score 0):

Нумерация столбцов, только вручную
при генерации массива столбцов

```
foreach ($cols as $number => $data) {
        $gridWiewColumns[] = [
            'attribute' => 'attr_' . $number,
            'label' => $number,
            'content' => <function ($model){}>//если нужен кастомный вывод
        ]
}

GridView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'columns' => $gridWiewColumns,
            ]);
```